# TextBox.TextChange to update an onscreen ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, forms, search, textbox, listbox

Now this might not sound horribly cryptic, but I'm a little new to handling on-screen elements and `Form`s and such in `C#` so bear with me here. It's also going to be a bit of a long one, as I feel I should provide as much information as possible.

I have a `TextBox` object, which is added to my `fSelect` (which is my `Form` in this case), and it's done like this:

```
TextBox searchBox = new TextBox();
fSelect.Controls.Add(searchBox);
searchBox.Location = new Point(40, 255);
searchBox.Width = 520;
searchBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(searchBox_TextChanged);
```

Now, as you can see every time something changes in the `TextBox` a certain operation is carried out. That operation would be:

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox s = (TextBox)sender;
    bool b = false;
    List<string> f = new List<string>();

    ListBox updatedLb = new ListBox();
    updatedLb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(568, 255);
    updatedLb.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;

    foreach (string value in lb.Items)
    {
        if (value.IndexOf(s.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            f.Add(value);
            b = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < f.Count; i++)
    {
        updatedLb.Items.Add(f[i]);
     }

    s.FindForm().Controls.Remove(lb);

    s.FindForm().Controls.Add(updatedLb);

}
```

Looking at that code, there's one element that needs explanation, `lb`. `lb` is in this case a `public` `ListBox` which contains a set amount of `string` elements. It is defined as a `ListBox` outside any method.

Now, in the method my `searchBox` was defined I filled my `lb` as follows:

```
foreach (string value in list)
{
    lb.Items.Add(value.title);
}
```

(If it matters, I should also mention that the adding of `string`s to `lb` happens before it is inserted into the `fSelect` `Form` later.)

Now, for those who haven't guessed my question yet; I wish to present a user with a `Form` that has a `ListBox` on it. The elements in this `ListBox` will be whatever elements contain the `string` the user types into `searchBox`, AS the user types it.

The problem is, that the search is only carried out once, and the only thing that is searched for is the first key the user puts in the `searchBox`. IE: If I was the user and I was going to search for "key", and the first letter was "k", the list would update to show anything with "k" in the title. But when I tried to type the "e" it would not update or change. It would also not go revert back to the old list if the user removes part of the text in `searchBox`.

How do I go about getting a `Form` that shows me a `ListBox` with elements based on what a user entered into `searchBox`?

Comment: I seemed to have stopped a sentence midway through. Brainfart. Cleaned it up now, sorry readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are looping though `lb`, which you delete the first time the `text_Changed`-Event triggers. So you don't have any items more that you can loop through and filter your `ListBox`. The easiest way to fix that would be not getting the items you loop though from the `ListBox` itself, but from a `List<string>` that you use to supply the `ListBox`.

**Edit**

Here's the way I'd do it:

In your form class you add a `List<string>`, this list is the base for your ListBox.

```
List<string> listBoxItems = new List<string>();
```

Now you can fill this list in your constructor with the items you want. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list) are some ways to do it. For my example I'll just add all the items manually for simplicity.

```
listBoxItems.Add("Item1");
listBoxItems.Add("abc");
listBoxItems.Add("CDE");
listBoxItems.Add("Abra");
```

Then you want to fill your `ListBox` with the items from your `List`.

```
foreach (var s in listBoxItems)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Now you just need to handle the `Text_Changed`-Event. Instead of creating a new ListBox every time, you just edit the one we already have in the form and instead of looping though the items in the `ListBox`, which are already filtered, you loop though all the item saved in your `List<string>`.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox s = (TextBox)sender;

    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach (string value in listBoxItems)
    {
        if (value.IndexOf(s.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In your code, you created a new ´ListBox´ each time you go into the loop, but you still try to use the items from your old one.

I hope this helps,

Dominik

Comment: I might be a little slow, but I'm not sure I understand. Could you show me in code? +1 though, no doubt!

Comment: I'll add a more detailed answer later. Have a look at the listBoxes you add in your code. You remove lb and try to loop through it again.

Comment: Alright, thanks. If no one else gives it a poke, I'll wait for that :)

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer with some code. Look through it and ask if you don't understand something.